# Deploy GitLab docker image on mac: Cannot see gitab.example.com

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ce, gitlab-ee

I am trying to run Gitlab Docker image on mac Big Sur locally following the steps from documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html . And always cannot see locally  https://gitlab.example.com. I tried both Gitlab EE and CE, and different versions of images, including latest. I also tried to use usual Docker basic run and docker-compose. I also updated Docker Desktop to latest version 4.10.1. I refined the logs and for all cases I have same error in Gitally log below:

**~/gitlab/logs/gitaly/current:**

```
{"level":"warning","msg":"[core] [Channel #2 SubChannel #4] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {\n  \"Addr\": \"/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/run/gitaly-344/sock.d/ruby.0\",\n  \"ServerName\": \"/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/run/gitaly-344/sock.d/ruby.0\",\n  \"Attributes\": null,\n  \"BalancerAttributes\": null,\n  \"Type\": 0,\n  \"Metadata\": null\n}. Err: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/run/gitaly-344/sock.d/ruby.0: connect: no such file or directory\"","pid":344,"system":"system","time":"2022-07-26T09:57:38.226Z"}
{"level":"warning","msg":"[core] [Channel #3 SubChannel #5] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {\n  \"Addr\": \"/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/run/gitaly-344/sock.d/ruby.1\",\n  \"ServerName\": \"/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/run/gitaly-344/sock.d/ruby.1\",\n  \"Attributes\": null,\n  \"BalancerAttributes\": null,\n  \"Type\": 0,\n  \"Metadata\": null\n}. Err: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/run/gitaly-344/sock.d/ruby.1: connect: no such file or directory\"","pid":344,"system":"system","time":"2022-07-26T09:57:38.228Z"}
{"level":"warning","msg":"spawned","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","bin/ruby-cd","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","344","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/run/gitaly-344/sock.d/ruby.0"],"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.0","supervisor.pid":400,"time":"2022-07-26T09:57:38.228Z"}
{"address":"/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket","level":"info","msg":"listening at unix address","time":"2022-07-26T09:57:38.234Z"}
{"level":"warning","msg":"spawned","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","bin/ruby-cd","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","344","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/run/gitaly-344/sock.d/ruby.1"],"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.1","supervisor.pid":401,"time":"2022-07-26T09:57:38.234Z"}
```

But I am not sure that this is the case - also checked other logs and seems to me no errors in other logs - but of course I will be happy to provide more logs if you want.

**This is my 'docker ps -a' status, docker version: 4.10.1, is run with docker-compose:**

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  container_name: 'gitlab'
  restart: unless-stopped
  hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
    - '22:22'
  volumes:
    - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

**list of docker active containers says container is healthy - but actually I see nothing in browser via https://gitlab.example.com.**

```
sudo docker ps -a 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                    PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
b0fb6252c7f3   gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest       "/assets/wrapper"        3 days ago     Up 3 minutes (healthy)    0.0.0.0:22->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp                           gitlab
```

**I also tried to add docker host IP to my hosts file - but no success:**

```
192.168.31.182 host.docker.internal
192.168.31.182 gateway.docker.internal
192.168.31.182 gitlab.example.com
```

I still see nothing in browser by https://gitlab.example.com

Comment: That's just a placeholder URL... Did you replace `gitlab.example.com` with your actual GitLab instance URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding more info to  @sytech "That's just a placeholder URL... Did you replace gitlab.example.com with your actual GitLab instance URL?"

You either need to add an /etc/hosts, setting to route gitlab.example.com to localhost or modify that to be localhost

```
  hostname: 'localhost'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'localhost'
```

These settings are telling the nginx proxy what url should be forwarded to gitlab. That's useful when you're running multiple sites from one server. If you are just running it locally, you should just use localhost.

> I also tried to add docker host IP to my hosts file - but no success:

You are forwarding the ports from the docker ip. Just use localhost. It probably didn't work because the docker IP you're looking at is for a different docker network.

Comment: Brandon Kauffman thank you a lot! I just changed docker host IP to localhost in my hosts file - as you advised. And then added 2 ENV vars:
export DOCKER_CLIENT_TIMEOUT=120
export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=120

And after that I can see GitLab UI via https://gitlab.example.com/users/sign_in

Really appericated!